# Ruby on Rails Submit button only works on refreshing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

Basically I have a show page for b_page and I have rendered a new partial inside (for page_posts) and the submit button for it only works if it the page is refreshed or if the link is directly opened from the browser. I've checked and there are no missing divs or unopened tags etc, hence it's not an HTML issue.

Maybe it's a Turbolinks issue cause this happens in almost all of the app and if so here's my `application.js.erb`:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-tagsinput
//= require sync
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require jscolor
//= require_tree .
//= require owl.carousel
//= require turbolinks
```

How can I fix this? Here's the link to [`show.html.erb`](https://github.com/Hisaan-Anjum/friends/blob/master/app/views/b_pages/_show1.html.erb).

Comment: It is turbolinks.  Isn't jquery.turbolinks plugin deprecated?

Comment: Holy shit! there are a lot of requires haha It's probably Turbolinks messing around. Try to put "require turbolinks" after "require jquery_ujs". And, as commented above, I think you can remove the gem "jquery.turbolinks".

Answer (score 1):

You must be using `$(document).on('ready', function(){})`

Change it to `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function (){})`, this forces JavaScript to load at the time page is viewed.